# joint pdf of X and Y

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

the joint pdf of X and Y is defined as:  \[
f_{X,Y}(x,y)
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{2}, & \text{if } 0\leq  x \leq 1 \text{,}x\leq  y \leq 1 \\
\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if } 0\leq  x \leq 1 \text{,}0\leq  y \leq x \\
\end{cases} \]
a)compute the marginal probability density functions $$f_{X}(x),f_{Y}(y)$$

b)compute the conditional probability density function$$f_{Y|X}(y|x)$$

c)use (b) to compute the conditional expectation of Y conditioned on X=x:E(Y|X=x)

can someone please go over my answers to see if I'm correct
$$f_{X}(x)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{3}{2}dy+\int_{0}^{x}(\frac{1}{2})dy=1.5-x$$
$$ f_{Y}(y)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx=\int_{y}^{1}\frac{3}{2}dx+\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{2}dx=1.5-y$$
$$ f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{f_{X,Y(x,y)}}{f_{X}(x)}=\frac{0.5+\frac{3}{2}}{f_{X}(x)}=\frac{2}{1.5-x}$$
$$E(Y|X=x)=\int yf_{Y|X=x}(x,y)dy=\int_{0}^{x}y\frac{2}{1.5-x}dy+\int_{x}^{1}y\frac{2}{1.5-x}dy$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with your integration ranges.

You have $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \tfrac 3 2 \raise{0.5ex}\chi_{0<x<y<1}+\tfrac 1 2 \raise{0.5ex}\chi_{0<y<x<1}$

So $\displaystyle f_X(x) = \left(\int_0^x \tfrac 1 2 \operatorname d y+\int_x^1 \tfrac 3 2 \operatorname d y \right)\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{0<x<1} = (\tfrac 3 2 - x)\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{0<x<1}
\\ \displaystyle f_Y(y) = \left(\int_0^y \tfrac 3 2 \operatorname d x+\int_y^1 \tfrac 1 2 \operatorname d x \right)\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{0<y<1} = (y+\tfrac 1 2) \raise{0.5ex}\chi_{0<y<1}$

And so on...

---

$\mathsf E(Y\mid X=x) = (\tfrac 32 - x)^{-1}\left(\int_0^x \tfrac y 2 \operatorname d y+\int_x^1 \tfrac {3 y}2 \operatorname d y \right)\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{0<x<1} = \dfrac{3-2x^2}{6-4x}\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{0<x<1}$